Problem with realization of Asynchronous ALOHA
I need to make async ALOHA, i have code of sync ALOHA, but i have a problem with turning it in async, so i need help with changing this. Code was made in jupyter lab on python language. it is necessary to make sure that messages can be sent not only at the beginning of the window, but at any time, the very concept of windows is not very appropriate here.
Here a code of sync ALOHA:
import numpy as np
import random
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def exp(lambd):
    return -np.log(np.random.random()) / lambd

def Poisson(lambd):
    if lambd >= 1:
        return 1
    s = 0.0
    k = -1
    while True:
        s += exp(1)
        k += 1
        if not s < lambd:
            break
    return k

def generate_new_tasks(lambd, num_windows):
    return [Poisson(lambd) for _ in range(num_windows)]

def simulate_interval_adaptive_aloha(M, lambd, num_windows):
    success_count = 0
    conflict_count = 0
    empty_count = 0
    queue_lengths = []
    delays = []
    window_sizes = []
    
    W_t = M
    queues = [[] for _ in range(M)]
    current_time = 0
    
    new_tasks = generate_new_tasks(lambd, num_windows)
    
    for window in range(num_windows):
        if window < len(new_tasks):
            new_task_count = new_tasks[window]
            for _ in range(new_task_count):
                station = random.randint(0, M - 1)
                queues[station].append(current_time)
        
        total_packets = sum(len(q) for q in queues)
        queue_lengths.append(total_packets)
        
        transmitting_stations = []
        for i in range(M):
            if queues[i]:
                chosen_window = random.randint(1, W_t)
                if chosen_window == 1:
                    transmitting_stations.append(i)
        
        if len(transmitting_stations) == 0:
            empty_count += 1
        elif len(transmitting_stations) == 1:
            success_count += 1
            station = transmitting_stations[0]
            entry_time = queues[station].pop(0)
            delays.append(current_time - entry_time)
        else:
            conflict_count += 1
        
        window_sizes.append(W_t)
        current_time += 1
    
    average_queue_length = statistics.mean(queue_lengths) if queue_lengths else 0
    average_delay = statistics.mean(delays) if delays else 0
    output_intensity = success_count / num_windows if num_windows > 0 else 0

    return success_count, conflict_count, empty_count, average_queue_length, average_delay, output_intensity, window_sizes
M = 10
num_windows = 100000
lambda_values = np.linspace(0.1, 0.9, 40) # уменьшил количество лямбда для лучшей читаемости графика

throughputs = []
queue_lengths = []
delays = []
window_sizes_list = []

success_rates = [] 
conflict_rates = []
empty_rates = []
average_window_sizes = []

for lambd in lambda_values:
    success_count, conflict_count, empty_count, queue_length, delay, throughput, window_sizes = simulate_interval_adaptive_aloha(M, lambd, num_windows)
    throughputs.append(throughput)
    queue_lengths.append(queue_length)
    delays.append(delay)
    window_sizes_list.append(window_sizes)

    success_rates.append(success_count / num_windows)
    conflict_rates.append(conflict_count / num_windows)
    empty_rates.append(empty_count / num_windows)
    average_window_sizes.append(np.mean(window_sizes))

print(success_rates)
print(conflict_rates)
print(empty_rates)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 20))

# График 1: Средняя задержка
plt.subplot(6, 1, 1)
plt.plot(lambda_values, delays, 'b-', label='Средняя задержка')
plt.xlabel('λ (интенсивность входного потока)')
plt.ylabel('Средняя задержка d(λ)')
plt.title('Зависимость средней задержки от интенсивности входного потока')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# График 2: Среднее число пакетов
plt.subplot(6, 1, 2)
plt.plot(lambda_values, queue_lengths, 'g-', label='Среднее число пакетов')
plt.xlabel('λ (интенсивность входного потока)')
plt.ylabel('Среднее число пакетов N(λ)')
plt.title('Зависимость среднего числа пакетов от интенсивности входного потока')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# График 3: Пропускная способность
plt.subplot(6, 1, 3)
plt.plot(lambda_values, throughputs, 'r-', label='Пропускная способность')
plt.xlabel('λ (интенсивность входного потока)')
plt.ylabel('Пропускная способность S(λ)')
plt.title('Зависимость пропускной способности от интенсивности входного потока')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()


# График 5: Вероятность Успеха
plt.subplot(6, 1, 4)
plt.plot(lambda_values, success_rates, 'g-', label='Вероятность успехов')
plt.xlabel('lambda_values')
plt.ylabel('Среднее число пакетов N(λ)')
plt.title('Зависимость вероятности успеха')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# График 6: Вероятность Конфликта
plt.subplot(6, 1, 5)
plt.plot(lambda_values, conflict_rates, 'r-', label='Вероятность Конфликта')
plt.xlabel('lambda_values')
plt.ylabel('Пропускная способность S(λ)')
plt.title('Зависимость вероятности конфликта')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# График 7: Вероятность Пусто
plt.subplot(6, 1, 6)
plt.plot(lambda_values, empty_rates, 'm-', label='Вероятность Пусто')
plt.xlabel('lambda_values')
plt.ylabel('Средний размер окна')
plt.title('Зависимость вероятности пусто')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

This code works fine for me, it have normal results. Here is Graphics of how looks results of sync ALOHA.
I tried some changes and its don't help
I understand that sync ALOHA is modification of async ALOHA, but how to downgrade it i don't understand.
Sync modification is that there are so-called windows that are synchronizing signals. Subscribers can report the presence of messages and start transmitting them only at the beginning of the window. In the original version, messages should be sent at any time.
